# How can I run buildah inside rootless podman container?

Tags: containers, podman, buildah, rootless

I have tried to add fuse device to container, but it failed.

```
/] podman run -it --rm --device /dev/fuse --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE -v /search:/search  centos8-test

/]# buildah build-using-dockerfile /search/kirbyzhou/sgbuild_Dockerfile/centos8-base
kernel does not support overlay fs: 'overlay' is not supported over <unknown> at "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay": backing file system is unsupported for this graph driver
ERRO exit status 125
```

It seems some special rights should be taken.

Comment: In another question it was suggested _The solution is to avoid the overlay on overlay situation_ (See https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/error-executable-file-ls-not-found-in-path-no-such-file-or-directory-oci-runtime-command-not-found-error/25034/2?u=eriksjolund ). Maybe it's a similar problem here?

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue opened on this right now.  I am not sure if this is possible.  Seems to be fighting against the User Namespace.

Of course you can just run `podman build` or buildah natively.

Lets continue to discuss this in the issue.